# NServiceBus.LicenseManager No valid license could be found

Tags: c#, messaging, nservicebus

Recently I've started to learn NServiceBus, But when I try to run a simple console app ([This](https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/nservicebus-step-by-step/1-getting-started/) for instance) I will face this message:

```
2019-09-18 11:20:46.386 INFO  NServiceBus.LicenseManager No valid license could be found. Falling back to trial license with start date '2019-09-18'.
```

How long can I use the free trial? And is there any long-life-free-tier(!) for personal and educational purposes?

P.S: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657809/nservicebus-license) article which say:

> Express Edition: You can use it for free with these limitations:
>
> All the publishers and subscribers are: On one (the same) machine
>   (meaning you can have NServiceBus only running on one box) And that
>   machine has no more than 4 cores. (You can't have a distributed model
>   at all with this license.) You only can have one worker thread with
>   this license.

But it doesn't mention any timed free trial.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep using the free version. You can ignore the warning or try
to supress the warnings by putting this in your app.config (I use Log4Net):

```
<logger name="NServiceBus.LicenseManager">
  <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
<logger name="NServiceBus.AuditInvalidLicenseBehavior">
  <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
<logger name="NServiceBus.LogErrorOnInvalidLicenseBehavior">
  <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```